# Dell XPS 15 9530 Ubuntu 22.04 compatibility

Tags: 22.04, xps

I would like to buy an XPS 15 9530 https://www.dell.com/fr-fr/shop/ordinateurs-portables-et-2-en-1/ordinateur-portable-xps-15/spd/xps-15-9530-laptop/cn95302sc, and I want to know if it's possible to install ubuntu 22.04 on it without having trouble with hardware incompatibilities.

configuration :

- i9-13900H
- NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 4070
- 32 Go DDR5

Thank you

Comment: Most likely it would work. However, this is a volunteer-run site, and we cannot guarantee anything. However, note that newer versions of Ubuntu are more compatible with newer hardware, so if something does not work well in 22.04, chances are, it may work with Ubuntu 23.04 or the upcoming 23.10